# How should i execute laravel migrations on an ecs cluster

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, database-migration

I have an architecture built on **AWS** container service with laravel running as an **api service** to my **JS app**.

My question is: **What is the best way to execute migrations?**

My assumption is with multiple instances of the same laravel app running in the cluster I risk issues with the app themselves running the migrations at the same time. right ?

What is the best way to run migrations on the database with no downtime for our clients ? maybe an external service specifically designed to run migrations on a mirror db ?

**Arch outline :**

1. ecs - laravel (5-10 services)
2. ecs - JS (10-20 services)
3. rds - mysql db (1 ec2 instance)

Comment: we use flyway for simplicity but there is noting about seamless. also we run our stack on mesos (analog of AWS ECS) - almost every docker orchestrator supports blue-green code deployment. You should google "badoo deploy" - they had same problems for php app. And think about api versioning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app containers should not run administrative tasks like migrations, or you will get contention with multiple instances or useless operations at restart.

From reading a few articles, the clean solution seems to run a one-off task to perform migrations.  This is similar to hwo things work on Heroku for example.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Comment: can you comment out what are those articles?

Comment: This answer probably mentions AWS Standalone tasks that you can run based on your Task Definitions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_run_task.html